# spring-security-oauth AuthenticationManager inject order

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm having the weirdest issue at hand. Having an application secured by spring-seucrity-oauth(2) the authentication suddenly stopped working and we can't find what's going wrong. 
Well actually we can. It's the authenticationManager that is injected *too late*. When configuring the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` the `authenticationManager` is not yet injected. For that reason the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer creates a list of tokenGranters without the ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.

We have no idea on what could cause this behaviour or how we could solve or work around it.

Any advise or help is appreciated!

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class**:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer  
@Configuration
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

     @Inject
     private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
       endpoints
             .tokenStore(tokenStore)
             .prefix("/api")
             .authenticationManager(authenticationManager); // when this method is called authenticationManager is null 
     }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // when I check authentionManager here, it is injected
}
```

This is how the authenticationManager bean is exposed and created.

**SecurityConfigurer.class:**

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
```

Comment: Something is forcing your `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` to be instantiated early. It's not possible to say what that is from the code you posted. Can you re-create the issue in a complete minimal project and post a link to that instead?

Comment: We are seeing the same issue with 2.0.6.RELEASE across different machines. Some are fine, some are not. Any update on this?

Comment: We figured out our issue. We actually had 2 classes annotated with @EnableAuthorizationServer. User error.